# Kernel WARNING /build/linux-EO9xOi/linux-4.4.0/lib/kobject.c:210

Tags: boot, kernel

I get this kernel WARNING at boot time on a X399-A mobo with
the latest BIOS and 16.04LTS. Is this concerning?

```
[    1.419431] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    1.419933] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 1 at /build/linux-EO9xOi/linux-4.4.0/lib/kobject.c:210 kobject_add_internal+0x23e/0x340()
[    1.420462] kobject: (ffff8808101ec9c0): attempted to be registered with empty name!
[    1.420997] Modules linked in:
[    1.421482] CPU: 5 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu
[    1.421970] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/PRIME X399-A, BIOS 0403 09/06/2017
[    1.422469]  0000000000000286 00000000cdcbb9cf ffff880819523c80 ffffffff813f7583
[    1.422975]  ffff880819523cc8 ffffffff81cfb3b8 ffff880819523cb8 ffffffff810812d2
[    1.423485]  ffff8808101ec9c0 00000000ffffffea ffff8808107d2810 0000000000000018
[    1.424037] Call Trace:
[    1.424580]  [] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[    1.425124]  [] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[    1.425632]  [] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[    1.426137]  [] ? kfree_const+0x22/0x30
[    1.426638]  [] kobject_add_internal+0x23e/0x340
[    1.427138]  [] ? kfree_const+0x22/0x30
[    1.427648]  [] kobject_add+0x75/0xd0
[    1.428182]  [] kobject_create_and_add+0x31/0x70
[    1.428712]  [] threshold_create_device+0x107/0x350
[    1.429231]  [] ? mcheck_vendor_init_severity+0x1a/0x1a
[    1.429719]  [] threshold_init_device+0x30/0x46
[    1.430205]  [] do_one_initcall+0xb3/0x200
[    1.430696]  [] ? parse_args+0x295/0x4b0
[    1.431184]  [] kernel_init_freeable+0x173/0x212
[    1.431697]  [] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    1.432217]  [] kernel_init+0xe/0xe0
[    1.432729]  [] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
[    1.433230]  [] ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[    1.433704] ---[ end trace 81eb86ab214f0aa0 ]---
```

Comment: Yes, symptomatic of a software error. At line 210 of `/build/linux-EO9xOi/linux-4.4.0/lib/kobject.c` (in the kernel source) `attempted to be registered with empty name!`

Comment: How can I help have this fixed? I can test a patch if given instruction on how to build the kernel.

Comment: First, AskUbuntu is NOT the place for a kernel debugging course, nor do I have the time. Second, you should check YOUR kernel changes, configuration changes, etc first. Third, suspect flakey hardware or connections. Build Ubuntu Kernel? Any search engine should get you started.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was my first post in this forum and I had little idea of what is the scope of what can be asked here. I was just trying to find anyone in the community that could indicate me to the proper path for a fix. I made no kernel changes. It is a completely new hardware and I noticed the warning so I was wondering how Ubuntu typically addresses issues like this. Maybe the proper forum is the Linux kernel forum but this kernel is built by ubuntu.

Comment: In case someone has a similar issue, the problem seems to be a mismatch between the kernel in 16.04LTS (both kernels 4.4 and 4.8 have this identical issue) and this ASUS X399-A motherboard as reported in the warning. I verified that using ubuntu kernel 4.10  makes the warning go away.